# Reading a table's column names in SQL Server, problem with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-schema

I'm trying to read names of columns of a table in SQL Server (later to be used in C#). 
The solution seems to be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'my_table_name'
```

It worked fine yesterday! but at the moment I can't get correct result. Because when I run the whole query it returns an empty table (columns' headers with no value) and when I run this

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

What I get doesn't contain the actual TABLE_NAMEs that I'm looking for. In the result, I get a table (query result) with these names in the column TABLE_NAME (instead of my actual tables' names):

- spt_fallback_db
- spt_fallback_dev
- spt_fallback_usg
- spt_monitor 
  spt_values

The values for the result column TABLE_CATALOG is always "master" and for the TABLE_SCHEMA column is "dbo". The result is like this:

```
TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME .....
-------------------------------------------
    master    |     dbo      | spt_monitor
-------------------------------------------
    master    |     dbo      | spt_values
                   .....
```

I think instead of reading the list of tables, it reads some other root-kind things.

Comment: You're connected to the wrong database. The `sys` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects return data relevant to the database you are connected to. You are clearly conencted to the `master` database, and there *shouldn't* be any user objects in there.

Comment: have you tried `use YourDBName;
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Comment: @Larnu Thank you. It is solved now! I thought as long as I write the name of the database in my query, it should connect to that database.

Comment: @vivek nuna Thank you. It's a very good idea, specially since I'm going to use this outside of the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to run query like this.

```
USE <YourDBName>;
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```